# curl command runs perfectly on linux but failed to run on windows

Tags: xml, linux, windows, curl

I'm writing a windows application with java to gain some data matrices. I'm using a curl command which runs perfectly on Linux environment. However, when I put that on windows it is completely useless and do nothing.

I'm pretty sure that problem is on xml part. I think the parser on the other end expecting new lines in order to parse that.I tried many methods like url encoding, reading the xml part from a xml file, parsing binary data but none of those worked.

This is the curl command I'm using..

```
curl -s -d "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<ewe mask=\"0x100\" hw_type=\"4\" br=\"BT\" release=\"5.5.0-0\">
  <probe>
    <core>
      <cam1>
        <cam1Tunings>
          <camTuningList xmlChil=\"list1\" UsedTuningId=\"1\" CamTuningVer=\"Jan  1 00:40:26\">
            <preset name=\"$FREQ MHz\" tuningId=\"1\" frequency=\"$FREQ.000M\" chSpacing=\"10\" symbolRate=\"3.154175 M\" modulation=\"256\" annex=\"1\" etrholds=\"ATSC Default\" pidThresholds=\"Default\" serviceThresholds=\"Default\" camThresholds=\"Default\" vbcThresholds=\"Default\" extractThumbs=\false\" disable=\"true\" referenceThresholds=\"[None]\"></preset>
          </camTuningList>
        </cam1Tunings>
      </cam1>
    </core>
  </probe>
</ewe>" -o output.html "http://$ADDR/probe/core/datalog.xml?"
```

I really appreciate any help or advice on this matter.

Comment: Have you tried `--show-error`, `--verbose`, and `--trace` options to curl?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by separating xml query to a .xml file and reading the query from the file.

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to debug this without being familiar with the system you're trying to interface with. However, I had some ideas that you might use to investigate this.

1. Your command uses `$FREQ` and `$ADDR`, which appear to be shell variables. If that is the case, are they set in your Windows environment?
2. Consider using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) on both Windows and Linux to see the exact HTTP request that is being sent, and compare the two. any difference should give you a hint of the issue.

(This question is mostly off-topic here, unfortunately.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes. I set FREQ and ADDR variables in windows environment. I also did use wireshark to compare the differences of both version and that's where I discovered xml new lines are missing on windows version. unfortunately, I also don't have a direct access to the system I'm trying to connect.